# How to print file.readline() line-number?

Tags: python, readline

```
f = open("saves\\" + plrname + "_inv.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for x in range(500):
    if (x in lines) == "True\n":
        print(x)
```

There are 500 lines in the .txt file with either "True" or "False"
I want the program to read them and print which ones are true by their line number.
I've tried "for x in lines". I hope you can help me, thank you.

Example of how the txt file looks like:

```
True
True
True
False
False
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the built-in function [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, x in enumerate(lines):
    if x == "True\n":
        print(index, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

enumerate is your friend.

Something like:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for i,x in enumerate(lines):
     ...
```